# Force Postfix to ask autentication

Tags: email, authentication

If I try to telnet a popular SMTP server I get this messages:

```
telnet smtp.mail.yahoo.it 25
Trying <ip>...
Connected to <smtp banner>.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 <smtp host> ESMTP ready
EHLO example.host
250-<smtp host>
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 41697280
250-8 BITMIME
250 STARTTLS
MAIL FROM: <myaddress@example.com>
530 5.7.1 Authentication required
```

Now, if I try with my own server (Postfix) I am not asked for authentication after the MAIL FROM command. How can I get to that configuration?

Ps: It's not about rejecting connections, I have tried things like permit_sasl_authenticated and so on...

Thank you!

Comment: It because yahoo mail servers advertise AUTH command only over encrypted channel. At least you should add output of the 'postconf -n' to the question

Answer (score 0):

To achieve similar behaviour, i.e. to offer AUTH after TLS only, you may need to add `smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes` in postfix's `main.conf` file:

> Supporting AUTH over TLS only
>
> Sending AUTH data over an unencrypted channel poses a security risk.
>   When TLS layer encryption is required (`smtpd_tls_security_level =
>   encrypt`), the Postfix SMTP server will announce and accept AUTH only
>   after the TLS layer has been activated with STARTTLS. When TLS layer
>   encryption is optional (`smtpd_tls_security_level = may`), it may
>   however still be useful to only offer AUTH when TLS is active. To
>   maintain compatibility with non-TLS clients, the default is to accept
>   AUTH without encryption. In order to change this behavior, set
>   `smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes`.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> /etc/postfix/main.cf:
>     smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
> ```

Ref: http://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html#server_tls_auth

Comment: Actually it's not my case. I already offer auth only over TLS, the problem is that if the client doesn't give the AUTH command the connection goes on. The problem is to get AUTH before starting the MAIL FROM command like in the example, where I received the message "530 5.7.1 Authentication required". Thanks in advantage.